# Strip the + symbol from the_search_query

Tags: search

When using the_search_query to display search result on my site, the spaces between words are displayed with a **+** symbol.

So if a visitor searches for "wordpress plugins" the_search_query output in search.php returns

```
    wordpress+plugins
```

How can I remove the + symbol, and/or replace it with non-break space entity, like so .....

```
    wordpress plugins
    or
    wordpress&nbsp;plugins
```

I tried this approach but it is not working .....

```
    <?php 
        $string = the_search_query();
        $res = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $string);
        echo $res;
    ?>
```

Comment: The plus sign is automatically decoded to a space in the search query. If that doesn't happen in your installation you have a bug in your theme or in a plugin.

Comment: It must be the case in this instance, because neither of @Joshua's code samples fixed the problem (which you would expect them to do in normal circumstances). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, when I do things like this I use `str_replace()` [[Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)]

Using your above example it would be implemented like so:

```
<?php 
    $string = the_search_query();
    $res = str_replace("+", " ", $string);
    echo $res;
?>
```

That will replace any `+` with a space.

Or if you want the `&nbsp;` use this:

```
<?php 
    $string = the_search_query();
    $res = str_replace("+", "&nbsp;", $string);
    echo $res;
?>
```

On a minor note, this  question is not really WP related and may get bounced to StackOverflow or closed by a mod.

Comment: Thanks Joshua. I think @toscho might be right with his "theme/plugin bug" because neither of your code samples fix the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In which case uploading a clean version of the WP core files should fix the problem.